# Storing Array List Object in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

This method add new object into `ArrayList`

```
//get text from textview
time = date.getText().toString();
entry_d = entry.getText().toString();
dayName = day.getText().toString();

arrayList.add( new ArrayObject( dayName, entry_d ,time));
```

I am trying to add these 3 strings in `SharedPrefrences`. Here is my code:

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager             
                                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

This method only add one string at a time where as I want to add 3 strings in one go. Is there any method I can implement.

Comment: I hope this is you question and resolve by this answer, [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75003482/12748481](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75003482/12748481)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Convert your array or object to Json with Gson library and store your data as String in json format.

Save;

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);

editor.putString(TAG, json);
editor.commit();
```

Read;

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, "");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<ArrayObject>>() {}.getType();
List<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: For which Type Classes to import - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847997/convert-jsonstring-to-a-custom-java-arraylist

Comment: use import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Comment: what to do if arrayList is List<View> ?

Comment: Do not persist framework object or any complex object like view.

Comment: Two days I tried to add json content to array list. Thank you. I used get type and everything works

Answer (score 22):

### **Store Arraylist Using  Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit=prefs.edit();

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(your Arraylist Name);
edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
edit.commit();
```

### **Retrieve Arraylist from Shared Preferences**

```
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
List<String> sample=new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Comment: can we use a single set do add more than 1 array list...I have 3 string array list.May I use single set or 3 sets for 3 lists

Comment: @Prabs did you create separate sets/?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi this sets concepts didn't worked for my requirement..So I didn't implemented this concept..For testing,Yes I've created separate sets.

Comment: Sorry for that. it will support only Set<String> not others.

Comment: it's only for Set<String> :\ !

Comment: If the order of the elements is important, I would not recommend using the putStringSet() method, becasuse the in a Set the order of the elements is not deterministic. Probably in most cases it will be retrieved in the same order as it was saved, but it is not granted.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Hashset` for this. It will change the ordering of `Arraylist`. Use `Gson` instead.
If you wish to use `Hashset`, you will have to serialize and deserialize which will take up resources.