# Android create a list with different objects from JSON (with GSON)

Tags: java, android, json, list, gson

I want to create a list with different JSON objects. From my JSON URL I get an array with different types of objects like:

[
  {
  "type":0,
  "cityName":"Berlin",
  "location":"Germany"
 },
 {
  "type":1,
  "weather":"Sun",
  "degree":10
 }
]

For the different types of objects I've different classes.

CityObject.class

```
public class CityObject {

public CityObject(){}

public int type;
public String cityName;
public String location;
}
```

WeatherObject.class

```
public class WeatherObject {

public WeatherObject(){}

public int type;
public String weather;
public int degree;
}
```

Now I want to create one list with all of these objects. Like if the type of the first JSON object == 0, create a CityObject with the data from the JSON object and put it in the list. Maybe a way is go through the whole JSON Array, check the type of each JSON object and create a JAVA object of the respective class and put it in the list?

But the problem is I don't know how to check the type of the JSON object and then create an object of the respective class and put it in the list.

I followed a tutorial how to parse JSON with GSON but the tutorial just create a list of one type.

My class extends AsyncTask

```
try {
            //Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet linkURL = new HttpGet(SERVER_URL);

            //Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(linkURL);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    List<CityDeal> cityDeals = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, CityDeal[].class));
                    content.close();

                    handleCityDealsList(cityDeals);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                    failedLoadingCityDeals();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
                failedLoadingCityDeals();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
            failedLoadingCityDeals();
        }
```

List cityDeals = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, CityDeal[].class));

This create a list of only one type and not dynamicly, like generic classes.

I hope anyone can help me with my problem.

Comment: I already answer this in this post, in this part "If you want to save a array of Products. You do this:"

http://stackoverflow.com/q/28107647/3729490

Comment: This not really solved my problem. I want to know, how to create a list with different object types which I select from the type id of the JSON object.