# xamarin.android save List<MyClass> in OnSaveInstaneState

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to do a "ToDoListApp" and my problem is that when I add some tasks to do and then close the app everything is deleted and the app starts anew.

I saw some other similar questions and it seems the solution is `OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` but I have a  generic list with a class that I made `List<MyClass>`. My Problem is that when I write `outstate.Put…` there is no option for my array I can only choose between int, string, charsequence and parcelable. So my question is how can I save the state of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is a thing you should be doing using an SQLite mobile database instead, Can be done like so :

- Download the NuGet package `sqlite-net-pcl` by **Frank A. Krueger**
- Using SQLite, Create a SQLite connection object

  ```
  var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
  ```
- After you have established a connection create your table something like this :

  ```
   db.CreateTable<MyClass>();
  ```
- Then insert the data that you want to insert into to the table something like this:

  ```
   db.Insert(_yourClassObject);
  ```
- Retrieve Data something like this;

  ```
   var stock = db.Get<MyClass>(**yourPrimaryId**); //single object based on condition
   var stockList = db.Table<MyClass>(); //The list of all data in this table.
  ```

For a better understanding of how it works [refer this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm)

**Update**

If you want to do it using shared preferences the way to do it would be converting it to JSON and then storing it to preferences as a string something like this:

- Using Newtonsoft JSON package:

  ```
  List<MyClass> your_Object;
  your_Object=FooValueAssigned;// Assumed assignment
  string yourString=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_Object); //It accepts any object in your case give your list here
  ```
- Now Save it in shared preferences like this:

  ```
  ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
  ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
  editor.PutString("your_list", yourString);
  // editor.Commit();    // applies changes synchronously on older APIs
  editor.Apply();        // applies changes asynchronously on newer APIs
  ```
- Retrieve from shared preferences something like this:

  ```
  ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
  string mString = prefs.GetString ("your_list", <default value>);
  ```
- Convert it back to your object type something like this:

  ```
  var yourObjectFromPref= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(mString);
  ```

Comment: Is there a was to do it with sharedPreferences ?

Comment: @GeorgiYakov you can only save primitive values to SharedPreferences. If you really don't want to use sqlite then you could try this, though it is in Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107647/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences/28107791)

Comment: @GeorgiYakov Updating the answer have a look

Comment: @G.hakim Hello, what does exactly `your_Object=FooValueAssigned;` do?

Comment: Well nothing that is just an assumed assignment in your case you will assign your value, just did that so that you don't keep it null and get a null pointer exception

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: @G.hakim Ahh, I forgot to tell you. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(mString);` must actullay be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(mString);`. Could you edit it so that the answer is truly correct.

Comment: Sure not a problem