# How to save and load keys of a custom object locally?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, sharedpreferences

I have a custom object `questionObject` and I load a list of about 100 such objects from firebase and store it in an `ArrayList<questionObject> result`. I then sort the list `result` in descending order and pass it to a function `selectQuestionSet` in which I have to extract the first 5 questions which haven't been previously shown to the user. I need to store the keys of the objects which I have already shown and load them the next time I have to select another 5 questions to ensure there is no repetition.

How do I achieve this? I tried using SharedPreferences but it stores only primitive datatypes so it wasn't of much use to me.

Here is my customObject:

```
public class questionObject implements Comparable<questionObject>{
    public String question;
    public String option1;
    public String option2;
    public String option3;
    public String option4;
    public String explanation;
    public String correct_attempts;
    public String total_attempts;
    public int key;


    public questionObject(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4, String explanation, String correct_attempts, String total_attempts, int key) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.option4 = option4;
        this.explanation = explanation;
        this.correct_attempts = correct_attempts;
        this.total_attempts = total_attempts;
        this.key = key ;

    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }

    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }

    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }

    public String getOption4() {
        return option4;
    }

    public String getExplanation() {
        return explanation;
    }

    public String getCorrect_attempts() {
        return correct_attempts;
    }

    public String getTotal_attempts() {
        return total_attempts;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(questionObject comparestu) {
        float compareRatio= Integer.valueOf(((questionObject)comparestu).getCorrect_attempts ())/Integer.valueOf(((questionObject)comparestu).getTotal_attempts ());

        return Float.compare(compareRatio,  Integer.valueOf(this.total_attempts)/Integer.valueOf( this.total_attempts ) );

    }
}
```

And these are the functions I am using:

```
public void selectQuestionSet(ArrayList<questionObject> result){
        int count = 0;
        Collections.sort(result);
        for (questionObject object: result) {
            if(count < 4 && checkUsage ( object.key )){
                //display the question
                //append key to stored list
            }

        }
    }

    public boolean checkUsage(int key){
        //Check whether key already used or not here
        return false;
    }
```

What should I write in the above functions to get 5 questions from the `result` object whose `key` is not in the stored keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to store the keys in SharedPrefernces

As the keys are of `int` type, you could store them in the `SharedPrefrences`

Or another approach would be serialize the object and then store the entire object. For that you can refer to [How to save List<Object> to SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107647/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences)