# Editing and saving an ArrayList<> that has been passed to another activity

Tags: java, android

I am making a frisbee logger and have an `ArrayList` of `Team` objects. Each `Team` has an `ArrayList` of `Player` objects. Everything is using `Serializable` properly to be sent using `Intent`.

In my main activity I am displaying the list of `Team` objects in a `ListView` and an option to add another `Team` (only a name is needed). Once a `Team` is selected I pass the object to another activity using `Intent`. On this second activity I have it display the list of `Player` objects and have fields to enter another player object into the passed list.

When I return to the main activity and go back to the add `Player` activity, what I have added is gone.

I cannot use `static` because there is obviously more than one `Team` object. I think passing back the changed `ArrayList` could work but that seems a little lame, time-consuming, and frustrating.

Is there a built-in way in Android Studio that does this or am I on my own?

**Note: I am not using SQLite as suggested in the comments**

There's not a whole lot to show on this but here it is I guess:

MainActivity.java

```
private static ArrayList<Team> listOfTeams = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<Game> listOfGames = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView gameList, teamList;

.....

teamList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Team t = (Team)teamList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        viewTeam(t);
    }
});

.....

//Item select in teamList. Start the TeamViewActivity
public void viewTeam(Team t)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TeamViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("teamView",t);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

TeamViewActivity.java

```
private Team team;
private ListView rosterList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_view);

    rosterList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playerList);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

    if(extras!=null)
    {
        if(extras.get("teamView")!=null)
        {
            team = (Team) extras.get("teamView");
        }
    }

    populateRosterList(team.getRoster());
}

public void addPlayerToRoster(View view)
{
    String checkFirst = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstText)).getText().toString();
    String checkLast = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastText)).getText().toString();
    String checkNumber = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberText)).getText().toString();

    if(!checkNumber.equals(""))
    {
        team.addPlayer(checkFirst, checkLast, Integer.parseInt(checkNumber));

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstText)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastText)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberText)).setText("");

        populateRosterList(team.getRoster());
    }
}

public void returnToMain(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("teamView", team);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void populateRosterList(ArrayList<Player> list)
{
    ArrayAdapter<Player> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.activity_list, R.id.genericText, list);
    rosterList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: You probably could use SQLite, if I understand correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider your concept:**

You serialize an object, i.e. you transform it into a transferrable format which is then **copied** over to the other activity and reconstructed as a **new** instance.

Consequently, you alter another instance, which is not available in the previous activity, if you do not return it - again, serialized - and finally reconstruct and copy it back into the respective instance.

What you need is a shared memory storage in your application, which can alter and retrieve data cross-activity **OR** a proper data routing using Intents w/ ISerializable.

**Options:**

1. Always serialize objects and pass and copy them around.
   -> No multithreaded alteration, possibly slow, unbeautiful
2. Singleton application with global data storage ir Context Object (I do NOT recommend the due to memory management and Garbage
   Collection inbetween Activity Switches BUT for consistency I'd
   wanted to mention this option)
3. SQLite3
   -> Quick, Simple and Scalable, But a bit cumbersome to get started with
4. Any other file-structure stored and maintained in the data folder
   -> I'd expect a lot of boilerplate code here, and low performance
5. Webservice and remote database
6. Proper component setup, i.e. initialize all accessing components in your software with the appropriate reference to the data structs using for  example fragments (Thanks to @mismanc, I actually missed that option initially)

In general you could abstract all that away using services and repositories, which allows you to under-the-hood test options like 3. 4. And 5. and find your best solution, and in addition, keeo the accessing code simple and clean.

Comment: Using RealmDB, SQLBrite, or other sqlite libraries makes the Sqlite option less cumbersome

Comment: Thanks for the whole options list! I think I might have to go look into SQLite. I've seen it before but I haven't really used it myself. Some concurrency would be a nice addition so I might as well go for it

Comment: Please consider @cricket_007 recommendations for integrating Sqlite!

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, then get your modified `Team` object from `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` to update your list.
[startActivityForResult example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kingfisher Phuoc mentioned you could use srartActivityForResult in case you don't want to change your approach.

Otherwise I will suggest you use either :

1. SharedPreference to store your arraylist object (by converting the arraylist to json then store it as string in json format). In the PlayerActivity you retrieve the data, manipulate it then save it. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984696/storing-array-list-object-in-sharedpreferences/22985657#22985657)
2. SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments. You hold the list in the `MainActivity` and pass its reference to `ShowListFragment` and `AddPlayerFragment` by interfaces. And you can also do other operations over them. If you dont want to use json or sqlite it can be a good way for you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ShowListener{
   public interface ShowListener{
       ArrayList<Team> getTeamList();
   }

   private ArrayList<Team> listOfTeams = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Team> getTeamList() {
    return listOfTeams;
   }

}
```

**ShowListFragment.java**

```
public class ShowListFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<Team> listOfTeams;
private ShowListener listener;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listener = (ShowListener)getActivity();
        listOfTeams = listener.getTeamList();
    }

}
```